# Externally editable strings in .NET assemblies?

Tags: .net, winforms

Is it possible to have strings in a .NET assembly that can be edited by some external tool? If it is, what tool?

For instance for a single-file Windows Forms application that can be installed simply by copying the single file (no installer required), and where a build system (or a manual process) configures the application on a per-client basis by changing/setting some strings before being distributed to the install location.

I know that this would normally be in a configuration file, but it is useful for simplicity of installation/configuration.

Answer (score 3):

Add a text file (or XML file) as an embedded resource. Before compliling you can modify its content to suit. Your application can the access the file and read the values contained therein.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [.NET Satellite Assemblies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_assembly#Satellite_assemblies) and the role that they have in language / string customisation.

[Satellite assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21a15yht%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Comment: don't the use of Satellite Assemblies result in more than one file - one or more .resx files? Then I can just as well use configuration files.